# python calculation frustration

Tags: python, calculation

So I’m doing a project for school we have to build a receipt my loop is being funky and not giving me a correct calculation. Plus I’m having trouble formulating a calculation for a 10 percent discount over a 100 purchase  and a 8 percent sales tax.

```py
itemName = ""
itemQuantity = ""
itemPrice = ""
moreItems = "Yes"
userResponse = ""
itemsPurchased = 0.0 # additional items purchased

itemName = input ('Please enter the name of the item: ')
itemQuantity = float(input ('Please enter the number items choosen: '))
itemPrice = float(input('Please enter item price: '))

while moreItems == "Yes":
    itemName = input ( ' Please enter the name of the item: ')
    itemsPurchased = float(input("Please enter the number of items puchased: "))
    itemPrice = float(input("Please enter item price: "))
    itemsPurchased +=1
    itemPrice +=1
    userResponse =input("Please enter Y or y if you have more items items to enter: ")
    if userResponse == " Y " or userResponse == "y":
        moreItems = "Yes"
    else:
        moreItems = "No"

total = (itemQuantity * itemPrice ) 

print (" item price: " + str  (total))

if total >= 100:
    print (total*.10  + total)
else:
    print(str(total))
```

***** I’m a beginner so please keep it simple for me!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: well you're adding 0.08, which is not how sales tax is calculated

Comment: so do you think i need a separate string? ( I did multiple versions of it) i know my order of operations is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You can try an oop approach. That way you would have a better overview and it's easier to extend the code.

[Object-orientation](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) is not as intuitive as functional programming for beginners but will give you big benefits when your programs grow.

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price


class Order:
    def __init__(self):
        self.positions = []

    def get_price(self):
        return sum([position.get_price() for position in self.positions])

class OrderPosition:
    def __init__(self, item_obj, quantity):
        self.item = item_obj
        self.quantity = quantity

    def get_price(self):
        return self.item.price * self.quantity

order = Order()
moreItems = True
while moreItems:
    itemName = input ( ' Please enter the name of the item: ')
    itemsPurchased = float(input("Please enter the number of items puchased: "))
    itemPrice = float(input("Please enter item price: "))
    item = Item(itemName, itemPrice)
    order.positions.append(OrderPosition(item, itemsPurchased))

    input_text = "Please enter Y or y if you have more items items to enter: "
    moreItems = input(input_text).lower() == 'y'

total = order.get_price()
print('Item price (without tax): ' + '${:,.2f}'.format(total))
if total >= 100:
    total -= total * 0.1
inclusive_tax = total * 1.08
print('Item price (with tax): ' + '${:,.2f}'.format(inclusive_tax))
```

Comment: I figured it out now the issue that I'm having is that I cant get add multiple items in my loop together. it will only add one :(